Using the Base R pipe to scale a column for a melted dataframe without modifying theoriginal dataframe
Minimal reproducible example:
I have a dataframe df with 3 columns, x, y, and  z. I want to plot x and y by melting the first two columns of df and passing the melted dataframe to ggplot. I want to scale x by 10 to plot it on a secondary axis. Currently I do the following:
df <- data. Frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length. Out = 6),
                    x = rep(c(0,1), 3),
                    y = runif(6, 0,10 ),
                    z = 1:6)
df_tmp <- df[, c("Date", "x", "y")]
df_tmp[["x"]] <- df_tmp[["x"]] * 10
df_melt <- df_tmp |>
            reshape2::melt(id.vars = "Date", 
                 variable.name = "Variable")

This works but seems clumsy - I really don't want to create the intermediate dataframe df_tmp. How can I rewrite this using the Base R (4.3.3) pipe so that I go from df to df_melt with x scaled as I want but without modifying df?
I'm looking for something that looks like:
df_melt <- df[, c("Date", "x", "y")] |>
            ???[["x"]] * 10 |>
            reshape2::melt(id.vars = "Date", 
                 variable.name = "Variable")

The real problem has one more issue: some of the variables names have spaces in them:
 df <- data. Frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length. Out = 6),
                        `x 1` = rep(c(0,1), 3),
                        y = runif(6, 0,10 ),
                        z = 1:6,
                        check.names = FALSE)

> df
        Date x 1          y z
1 2000-01-01   0 9.45631520 1
2 2000-02-01   1 8.70666686 2
3 2000-03-01   0 0.04369742 3
4 2000-04-01   1 8.76839895 4
5 2000-05-01   0 7.60757741 5
6 2000-06-01   1 7.90135112 6

How do I melt the dataframe using a pipe while preserving the name x 1 and not creating x.1
Many thanks in advance for your help
Thomas Philips

You can use base::transform() here:
df[, c("Date", "x", "y")] |>
    transform(x = x * 10) |>
    reshape2::melt(
        id.vars = "Date",
        variable.name = "Variable"
    )
#          Date Variable      value
# 1  2000-01-01        x  0.0000000
# 2  2000-02-01        x 10.0000000
# 3  2000-03-01        x  0.0000000
# 4  2000-04-01        x 10.0000000
# 5  2000-05-01        x  0.0000000
# 6  2000-06-01        x 10.0000000
# 7  2000-01-01        y  0.4958052
# 8  2000-02-01        y  6.4921748
# 9  2000-03-01        y  3.9126018
# 10 2000-04-01        y  9.3335531
# 11 2000-05-01        y  8.4794048
# 12 2000-06-01        y  9.4376755

Frankly, I like transform() because the syntax is very similar to dplyr::mutate(). However, note the warning in the docs:

This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting arithmetic functions, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument transform can have unanticipated consequences.

If this is of concern, you can also achieve the same using base::within():

Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data, possibly modifying (a copy of) the original data.

df[, c("Date", "x", "y")] |>
    within(x <- x * 10) |>
    reshape2::melt(
        id.vars = "Date",
        variable.name = "Variable"
    )
# ^^ same output

Other approaches
As noted in a comment by G. Grothendieck, you can use base::subset() rather than [, which looks nicer in pipelines:
df |>
    subset(select = c(Date, x, y)) |>
    transform(x = x * 10) |>
    reshape2::melt(id.vars = "Date", variable.name = "Variable")

Finally, if you want to do everything in base R, you can use the drop parameter of stats::reshape() to avoid the need to subset prior to reshaping:
x <- df |>
    transform(x = x * 10) |>
    reshape(
        drop = "z",
        varying = c("x", "y"),
        v.names = "value",
        timevar = "Variable",
        times = c("x", "y"),
        idvar = "Date",
        direction = "long",
        new.row.names = seq_len(nrow(df) * length(c("x", "y")))
    )

Having said that, I find the API for base::reshape() extremely awkward and pretty much never use it.

Thank you - I will move to within(). I have a follow up question. The actual names in the dataframe have spaces e.g. "NBER Dated Recessions". How can I preserve the spaces and not introduce dots when using transform() or within()? I have tried using backticks e.g. NBER Dated Recessions, but I still get a new variable name  NBER.Dated.Recession.

@ThomasPhilips usually the answer is check.names = FALSE but that happens when you create the data frame, not mutate it. I can't replicate the behaviour of these functions adding dots. e.g. data.frame("name with spaces" = 1,check.names = F)  |> within(name with spaces<-name with spaces * 1) doesn't add spaces. Neither does data.frame("name with spaces" = 1,check.names = F)  |> transform(name with spaces=name with spaces * 1)

check. Names = FALSE works perfectly for data frame creation, but I can't replicate your results with the backticks: transform(x 1  = (x 1 - 0.5)* 10), i.e. with backticks around x 1, still gives me a melted dataframe with x.1

@ThomasPhilips I don't think I quite understand. Can you edit the question with a reproducible example that leads to this issue?

Edited - Thanks for all the help @SamR!

@ThomasPhilips I still can't replicate the issue. With your new data I can do df |> within(`x 1` <- `x 1` * 10) |> reshape2::melt(id.vars = "Date", variable.name = "Variable") and there are no dots. Can you add the code that is causing this problem?

Aha! I had not changed from transform to within. Once I made the switch, it worked perfectly. Thanks a million.

Suggest replacing the first line of code in the answer with df |> subset(select = c(Date, x, y)) |>

The widespread and successful use of dplyr::mutate shows that using transform is not so bad.

@G.Grothendieck I have added that to the answer. I agree the NSE issue doesn't seem to be a huge deal most of the time, but occasionally it is a nightmare, so worth pointing out.

Thanks everyone. I'm trying to work in Base R as far as possible because the tidyverse tends to have unstable syntax. More than once, I have found that code that worked perfectly well a few months ago has stopped working or throwing errors. Base R tends to be much more stable.

This works for me.  No need to use within: df |>     subset(select = c(Date, \x 1`, y)) |>
transform(`x 1` = `x 1` * 10) |>
reshape2::melt(id.vars = "Date", variable.name = "Variable")`

Interesting twist: transform(x  1 = x 1 *10)  gives me dots in the name. transform(x  1 <- x 1 *10) preserves spaces! First time I have seen a clearcut difference between = and <-

transform(x 1 <- x 1) does not change x 1   Only = works.

You are right - In my excitement at seeing x 1 I forgot to check the values. I think I will stick with within. Thanks as always.
